# Applying style to particular character in textview

Tags: android

Currently I am using 26 `Textview` so that I can apply style to particular character depending on runtime situation.
But if I can able to apply style on particular character in textview I can achieve my goal using only one textview.

e.g.
If I want to make character 'M' red in following code. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="20dip" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="15dip" 
    android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
   android:textColor="#000000"/>`
```

Or anybody have better option than using 26 `TextView` it also welcome.

Comment: That's fine; just a little heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only 1 textview and change the color by Html.fromHtml()

Comment: There is an example at: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It will help you..

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin=45;
params.topMargin=70;
TextView textView=new TextView(this);
String text = "I Love <font color='red'>ANDROID !!!</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
textView.setTextSize(25);
rl.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Spannable

```
private SpannableString spanIt(String text, String queryText) {
    // search for query on text
    int startIndex = text.indexOf(queryText);
    int endIndex = startIndex + queryText.length();
    // spannable to show the search query
    SpannableString spanText = new SpannableString(text);
    if (startIndex > -1) {  
        spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), startIndex,
                endIndex, 0);
    }
    return spanText;
}
```

And then on textview..

```
tv.settext(spanIt("ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVXZ","M"));
```