# Textview placing each character on newline

Tags: android, textview

I want to place each character on new line.
I am using following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="12dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
    android:textSize="12dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

but I am getting output as follow(On some line 2 character are coming)

[image].

I know that I can use `\n` but anybody have better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's kind of a hack that'll work:

```
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ems="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />
```

This relies on the monospace typeface, where all characters have the same width.

Comment: what is use of property 'ems'? Using your answer i get 2 line in each row. But i used monospace in my layout it is working fine in my xml.

Comment: Hmm, for me it works right. "ems" makes it exactly one em wide, which is the width of the widest character in the typeface (M). So with monospace, it should be the width of 1 character.

Comment: If i put space between each character it is working with your layou for me.

Comment: Weird. Just tested it, I was previewing for a 3.7in WVGA screen preview and it looks fine, but if I do it on a 3.2in HVGA, it splits it to two characters per row. I don't know why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your getting 2 chars on each line is due to the static width of the view.  I really wouldn't approach this problem with a single view with a static width.

There are a lot of solutions to this, but based on the info you gave, I would probably create a single textview layout like you've done and dynamically inflate an array of textviews via code.  AKA each char in your string gets assigned to it's own textview.

Comment: See i can achive this using multiple textview. but for that i need 26 layout if u see my question. I was previously doing that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698382/applying-style-to-particular-character-in-textview

Comment: No, you misunderstood.  One layout.  You _inflate_ it 26 times via code.  Which inside an array is only going to be a few lines of code.

Comment: @user432209: Still a lot of unnecessary inflation, just adding `\n` would be a lot more effective, or if monospace is okay, my answer above.

Comment: Yes, and I realize it takes more time.  Your solution is fine too.  However, you're assuming that the OP is okay with changing a font to get what he wants.  I generally don't like to make these type of assumptions if I can help it.